# use checkbox for form to appear

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have made two forms in dojo of the type :-

Client name

Client Address
Physical

Postal

Telephone No

Fax No

Email

Address to

now i want a checkbox to appear on the screen with two options :- form 1 and form 2

when i click on form1 my frst form should appear and when i click on form2 the other form should appear.

i have made the two forms. but i am not being able to use the checkbox in the right manner

Comment: Can a user check both boxes to have both forms at the same time? If not, a radio button is more suitable.

Comment: yes .. but the usage is  a prob. i have made two html files for the two forms. and now i dont have any idea how to use teh checkbox